# Android: Use fastScroll in a WebView

Tags: android, webview, fastscroll

I'm writing an Android app that displays ridiculously long HTML pages in a WebView control (nothing I can do about that, it parses an external website).
Is there any way to make scrolling easier? I tried fastScroll but it looks like WebView doesn't support it. Any ideas?